# Ruby on rails default route on 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Current version i am using is

`Ruby = 1.8.7`, 
 `rails = 2.3.18`

and i have this `routes.rb` file in config directory

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

  map.root :controller => "home"
end
```

and i have created a file in `app/controllers` directory with name of `home_controller.rb`

with the below contents

```
class Home < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts 'Hello World';
  end
end
```

This is the url i have created this new rails project on.

`http://ctsdemo.com/demos/taurus/old/demoapp/public/`

but its not redirecting me to the home controller?

=-=-=-=-=-=-

**Update :**

I have updated the routes.rb file and specified the action as well.

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

  map.root :controller => "home", :action => "index"
end
```

Still same old page i am getting. its like routes file never gets accessed by rails??

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the action as well which in your case is `"index"`

```
map.root :controller => "home", :action => "index"
```

For more details you should refer [**Rails 2.3 routing**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/routing.html#using-maproot)

Comment: still the same
`http://ctsdemo.com/demos/taurus/old/demoapp/public/`

Shows the same page, i specified the action as you asked. copied your line and replaced with mine line.

Comment: do this also needs some sort of .htaccess file? like in apache??

Comment: You need to make sure nginix is set up properly

Comment: Because what i can see is the directory structure which I should not

Comment: i have hostgator hosting. what can be the fix?

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 2, I believe it must be:

```
map.root :controller => "home", :action => "index"
```

Comment: please check my question update.  even thou defining action didnt help. still routes.rb not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the comment right on top of the default `routes.rb` file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/railties/configs/routes.rb#L2), it tells you what you're doing wrong: "The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority". In other words: You need to declare the root before the fallback URLs.

Another note: If you care about security, consider removing the fallback URLs altogether (as [the other comment in the default `routes.rb` file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/railties/configs/routes.rb#L39-L40) suggests).

Last but not least: If this is an app that's running in production, consider upgrading to a current Rails version or use [Rails LTS](https://railslts.com) if you aren't already. And while you're at it, you should also upgrade to a supported Ruby version. IMO it's highly risky to run such an outdated stack in production.

Comment: actually its the new project created in hostgator using command `rails new` and edited the routes files with creating a controller file. 
and removed the index.html from public. as explained in the documentation of 2.3 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/getting_started.html

Comment: Then take a note what I wrote about route priority and order the routes accordingly. :) Also, if it's a new project, I STRONGLY suggest going with Rails 5.1 (or at least Rails 5.0). There's really no reason to use Rails 2.3 unless you have a legacy app that uses it.

Comment: im using Rails 2.3, because another project has been built on 2.3. and Ruby on Rails is very new to me. i don't even understand the coding. 
However there is certain code that i need to understand and convert it to php. But to understand rails i created a new project to understand on its MVC.